# Working on In-App-Update on Android. Stuck in some loop can you people help me out?

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile

Working on the new feature In-App-Update released in Google I/O 2019. Implementation is done as per the documentation.

Link : https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/in-app-updates

1. App looks for the new updated, if update found app downloads the new version and then install it.

Problem here : After installing app restarts. Again app shows update is available. Same flow appears. Stuck in this loop.

Can anybody has the experience in this in app update?.

Comment: + Confirming same issue. Tried both flexible and immediate methods. Everything goes well, but app version stays same. 
Cannot understand why people mark -1 to this question.

Answer (score 2):

I found resolution:

1. In-app update works only if You installed a **signed apk**
2. Also do not forget to add to **onResume** handling method for *DEVELOPER_TRIGGERED_UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS*.

Everything already written in [Official Manual](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/in-app-updates).